# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' -> JSON map to @dataclass Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, class, mapper

I have issue with parsing JSON. I would like to map JSON in to the python class. There is many tutorials but this one: https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-python is easy for me to understund how work this implementation.

but....

I have scenarios where from API i can received json response with some values or not. For example:

1: JSON

```
{
  "TrackResponse": {
    "Response": {
      "TransactionReference": {
        "CustomerContext": "",
        "XpciVersion": "1&amp;#x2e;0"
      },
      "ResponseStatusCode": 1,
      "ResponseStatusDescription": "Success"
    },
    "Shipment": {
      "Shipper": {
        "ShipperNumber": 000000
      },
      "ShipTo": {
        "Address": {
          "City": "TXT",
          "PostalCode": 123456,
          "CountryCode": "PL"
        }
      },
      "ShipmentWeight": {
        "UnitOfMeasurement": {
          "Code": "KGS"
        },
        "Weight": 9.5
      },
      "Service": {
        "Code": 11,
        "Description": "UPS Standard"
      },
      "ReferenceNumber": [
        {
          "Code": 4,
          "Value": "TEXT"
        },
        {
          "Code": 3,
          "Value": "TEXT2"
        }
      ],
      "ShipmentIdentificationNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "PickupDate": 20230315,
      "DeliveryDateUnavailable": {
        "Type": "Scheduled Delivery",
        "Description": "Scheduled Delivery Date is not currently available, please try back later"
      },
      "Package": {
        "TrackingNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "DeliveryIndicator": "Y",
        "DeliveryDate": 20230320,
        "Activity": [
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "TEXT",
                "PostalCode": "12-454",
                "CountryCode": "PL"
              },
              "Code": "M7",
              "Description": "Receiver",
              "SignedForByName": "xxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Status": {
              "StatusType": {
                "Code": "D",
                "Description": "Delivered"
              },
              "StatusCode": {
                "Code": "9E"
              }
            },
            "Date": 20230320,
            "Time": 81630,
            "GMTDate": "2023-03-20",
            "GMTTime": "07:16:30",
            "GMTOffset": "+01:00"
          },
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": "",
              "Description": "Receiver"
            },
            "Status": {
              "StatusType": {
                "Code": "M",
                "Description": "Shipper created a label, UPS has not received the package yet."
              },
              "StatusCode": {
                "Code": "MP"
              }
            },
            "Date": 20230315,
            "Time": 180237,
            "GMTDate": "2023-03-15",
            "GMTTime": "22:02:37",
            "GMTOffset": "-04:00"
          }
        ],
        "PackageWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "KGS"
          },
          "Weight": 9.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2: JSON

```
{
  "TrackResponse": {
    "Response": {
      "TransactionReference": {
        "CustomerContext": "",
        "XpciVersion": "1&amp;#x2e;0"
      },
      "ResponseStatusCode": 1,
      "ResponseStatusDescription": "Success"
    },
    "Shipment": {
      "Shipper": {
        "ShipperNumber": 000000
      },
      "ShipTo": {
        "Address": {
          "City": "TXT",
          "PostalCode": 123456,
          "CountryCode": "PL"
        }
      },
      "Service": {
        "Code": 11,
        "Description": "UPS Standard"
      },
      "ReferenceNumber": [
        {
          "Code": 4,
          "Value": "TEXT"
        },
        {
          "Code": 3,
          "Value": "TEXT2"
        }
      ],
      "ShipmentIdentificationNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "PickupDate": 20230315,
      "DeliveryDateUnavailable": {
        "Type": "Scheduled Delivery",
        "Description": "Scheduled Delivery Date is not currently available, please try back later"
      },
      "Package": {
        "TrackingNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "DeliveryIndicator": "Y",
        "DeliveryDate": 20230320,
        "Activity": [
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": {
                "City": "TEXT",
                "PostalCode": "12-454",
                "CountryCode": "PL"
              },
              "Code": "M7",
              "Description": "Receiver",
              "SignedForByName": "xxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Status": {
              "StatusType": {
                "Code": "D",
                "Description": "Delivered"
              },
              "StatusCode": {
                "Code": "9E"
              }
            },
            "Date": 20230320,
            "Time": 81630,
            "GMTDate": "2023-03-20",
            "GMTTime": "07:16:30",
            "GMTOffset": "+01:00"
          },
          {
            "ActivityLocation": {
              "Address": "",
              "Description": "Receiver"
            },
            "Status": {
              "StatusType": {
                "Code": "M",
                "Description": "Shipper created a label, UPS has not received the package yet."
              },
              "StatusCode": {
                "Code": "MP"
              }
            },
            "Date": 20230315,
            "Time": 180237,
            "GMTDate": "2023-03-15",
            "GMTTime": "22:02:37",
            "GMTOffset": "-04:00"
          }
        ],
        "PackageWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "KGS"
          },
          "Weight": 9.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so the difrences is in 1 Json there is  ShipmentWeight and in 2 Json is not

```
"ShipmentWeight": {
        "UnitOfMeasurement": {
          "Code": "KGS"
        },
        "Weight": 9.5
      },
```

This is one example but in my implementation there is many tags with the same situation.

error: _ShipmentWeight = str(obj.get("ShipmentWeight"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

besause there is no tag ShipmentWeight in 2 Json.

Python @dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class ShipmentWeight:
    UnitOfMeasurement: UnitOfMeasurement
    Weight: float

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'ShipmentWeight':
        _UnitOfMeasurement = UnitOfMeasurement.from_dict(obj.get("UnitOfMeasurement"))
        _Weight = float(obj.get("Weight"))
        return ShipmentWeight(_UnitOfMeasurement, _Weight)


@dataclass
class Shipment:
    Shipper: Shipper
    ShipTo: ShipTo
    ShipmentWeight: ShipmentWeight
    Service: Service
    ReferenceNumber: List[ReferenceNumber]
    ShipmentIdentificationNumber: str
    PickupDate: int
    ScheduledDeliveryDate: int
    ScheduledDeliveryTime: int
    DeliveryDateUnavailable: DeliveryDateUnavailable
    Package: Package

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Shipment':
        _Shipper = Shipper.from_dict(obj.get("Shipper"))
        _ShipTo = ShipTo.from_dict(obj.get("ShipTo"))
        _ShipmentWeight = ShipmentWeight.from_dict(obj.get("ShipmentWeight"))
        _Service = Service.from_dict(obj.get("Service"))
        _ReferenceNumber = [ReferenceNumber.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("ReferenceNumber")]
        _ShipmentIdentificationNumber = str(obj.get("ShipmentIdentificationNumber"))
        _PickupDate = int(obj.get("PickupDate"))
        _ScheduledDeliveryDate = int(obj.get("ScheduledDeliveryDate"))
        _ScheduledDeliveryTime = int(obj.get("ScheduledDeliveryTime"))
        _DeliveryDateUnavailable = DeliveryDateUnavailable.from_dict(obj.get("DeliveryDateUnavailable"))
        _Package = Package.from_dict(obj.get("Package"))
        return Shipment(_Shipper, _ShipTo, _ShipmentWeight, _Service, _ReferenceNumber, _ShipmentIdentificationNumber,
                        _PickupDate, _ScheduledDeliveryDate, _ScheduledDeliveryTime, _DeliveryDateUnavailable, _Package)




response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            xmlcontent = xml.fromstring(response.text)
            json_data = json.dumps(xmljson.badgerfish.data(xmlcontent))
            jsonstring = json.loads(json_data)
            root = Root.from_dict(jsonstring)
```

I will be very grateful for advice :)

I have try to set some properties for @dataclass, and search in google how to ignore map object if null.
In java will be something like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            om.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
            om.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
            trackResponse = om.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), UpsResponseJson.class);
```

but how to do this in Python ?

Solved: Maybe somone can use this:

```
def get_if_null(obj, tag_name, type):
    try:
        tag_name_result = type(obj.get(tag_name))
    except AttributeError as er:
        tag_name_result = None
    return tag_name_result
```

and use in @staticmethod

```
@dataclass
class Address:
    AddressLine1: str
    AddressLine2: str
    AddressLine3: str
    City: str
    PostalCode: str
    CountryCode: str
    StateProvinceCode: str

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Address':
        _AddressLine1 = get_if_null(obj, "AddressLine1", str)
        _AddressLine2 = get_if_null(obj, "AddressLine2", str)
        _AddressLine3 = get_if_null(obj, "AddressLine3", str)
        _City = get_if_null(obj, "City", str)
        _PostalCode = get_if_null(obj, "PostalCode", str)
        _CountryCode = get_if_null(obj, "CountryCode", str)
        _StateProvinceCode = get_if_null(obj, "StateProvinceCode", str)
        return Address(_AddressLine1, _AddressLine2, _AddressLine3, _City, _PostalCode, _CountryCode,
                       _StateProvinceCode)
```

Comment: If the problem is solved, post an Answer.

Comment: Why did you tag this XML? The purpose of tagging questions is to bring them to the attention of people with relevant knowledge. Please don't waste everyone's time by using inappropriate tags.

Comment: @MichaelKay Apologies for wrong XML TAG, corrected now.